# What is the best way to do multilabel/multifeature output classification in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, keras-layer

I have a dataset where every example has 50 output labels which are binary(either label present or not present). What should make as output in the last layer. One very naive way would be to add a Dense sigmoid layer as follows:

```
output = Dense(50, activation = 'sigmoid')(X)
```

But I think that optimizing for all labels at the same time would not be a good solution. So I think another way would be to train a separate network each for all the labers. But that would be too expensive. Is there any better method?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you actually tried what you call the naive solution?

Comment: Yes I tried it, but the accuracy seemed to be around 60%.

Comment: Well its really the only method, you have to tune the model to increase accuracy, just like any other ML model.